# Should .NET Standard Library Using Azure "Text to Speech" Be Platform Impacted?

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform, azure-cognitive-services

With an app built on Xamarin with the latest NUGET libraries, built with a .NET Standard library with a Cognitive Services class to access Azure "Text to Speech" using REST with Bearer accessToken protocol, the iOS app has no problems, but the Android app just started receiving error 400's in the responses. Shouldn't the request be the same as it is the same code? Is there something hidden in the request that indicates the platform?

Comment: What is the actual 4xx error? i.e. Have you exceed the concurrent requests allowed for your plan, etc..

Comment: What you’re saying makes sense. Could you please share the example of tutorial that you are trying to follow? Or perhaps just share your code with us

Comment: There are no concurrent request, just sequential. I am pretty sure that it was a collage of documents, not a tutorial that I referenced. If the same code is used by both platforms at the application level and works for one, why shouldn't it for the other? Do I have to now have to write platform specific code? It was working until yesterday when I upgraded NUGETs.

Answer (score -1):

what is your request SSML?

you could also try speech sdk 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk

Comment: I have working code in a .NET Standard library for iOS, so I don't need examples. The same code was working for Android a couple of days ago; something has change in the supporting libraries that has disabled it.

Comment: what supporting library do you refer to?